# Elasticsearch date format in mapping

Tags: date, elasticsearch

```
PUT test_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "default": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "dates": {
                        "match": ".*Date*|date",
                        "match_pattern": "regex",
                        "mapping": {
                            "format": "yyyyMMddhhmmss||yyyyMMdd||date_hour_minute_second_millis||date_time_no_millis||date_time||basic_date_time||basic_date",
                            "type": "date"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "createDate" : {
                  "type" : "date"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Values for createDate are yyyymmdd format(no time or zone) "createDate" : "20010801".

Now my search strings are formatted as below should find results, but currently none are found:

```
GET test_index/_search
{"query": {"range": {"createDate": {"gte": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "lte": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}}}
```

How can change mapping so I can fetch documents based on the above search query?

Answer (score 0):

You're querying just one day -> 1970-01-01 <= `createDate` <= 1970-01-01...
Have you tried using a more reasonable range?

When in doubt, you can add the `format` param to your range & verify if your datetimes were parsed correctly at index time using `script_fields`:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "createDate": {
        "gte": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "format": "date_optional_time"
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "formatted_date": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
                  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                     Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['createDate'].value.millis),
                     ZoneId.of('Europe/Vienna')
                  ).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to this, look the format added to createDate property. Don't know why, I am new to ES. But by chance it worked.

```
PUT test_index
    {
        "mappings": {
            "default": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                        "dates": {
                            "match": ".*Date*|date",
                            "match_pattern": "regex",
                            "mapping": {
                                "format": "yyyyMMddhhmmss||yyyyMMdd||date_hour_minute_second_millis||date_time_no_millis||date_time||basic_date_time||basic_date",
                                "type": "date"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "createDate" : {
                      "type" : "date",
                      "format": "yyyyMMddhhmmss||yyyyMMdd||date_hour_minute_second_millis||date_time_no_millis||date_time||basic_date_time||basic_date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

These are my search queries it tried with and i get same results with all three.

```
GET test_index/_search
{"query": {"range": {"createDate": {"gte": "2013-04-25T05:33:30.000Z", "lte": "2020-04-25T05:33:32.000Z"}}}}
GET test_index/_search
{"query": {"range": {"createDate": {"gte": "2013-04-25T00:00:00.000Z", "lte": "2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"}}}}

GET test_index/_search
{"query": {"range":{"createDate":{"gte": "20130425", "lte": "20200425"}}}}
```

Thank you jzzfs for your help.